# How to hash a string in Python

Tags: python

I simply want to hash a string (a Password) in Python 3. How do I do that?
What is a Simple Way of doing that? Could you please give a Coding example or Recommend me a Module that can use.

Comment: What do you mean by hashing? Like assigning a key to each value? Or like password encryption?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can hash values in Python 3 with Hashlib:

```
import hashlib
h = hashlib.new('sha256')#sha256 can be replaced with diffrent algorithms
h.update('Hello World'.encode()) #give a encoded string. Makes the String to the Hash 
print(h.hexdigest())#Prints the Hash
```

Comment: hashlib is part of core python - isnt it? (why pip install ?)

Comment: @balderman My Bad :/

Comment: What diffrent Algorithms can i use?

Comment: @copycode You can see all Algorithms usable by printing out `hashlib.algorithms_available()` but I recommend sicking to sha256 because some algorithms are old/outdated.

Comment: It should be noted that `h.update` adds/appends the new bytes `'Hello World'.encode()` to the `h` object. Meaning that repeating the last two lines from above, prints two different hashes because the second call creates the hash of the string "Hello WorldHello World".

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there can be an easier way than using the built-in keyword `hash`:

```
In [1]: hash("Hello, world!")
Out[1]: 7195831199436619873
```

Comment: should be mentioned here, that (at least in Python 3), this function does not guarantee to generate same values across processes (i.e. running `python -c "print(hash('abcde'))"` in terminal repeatedly, outputs different numbers)